# Why READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not working for XML file on Android

Tags: android

Goal: To open and read an XML file on Android
Problem: Getting permission denied even though READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has been granted.

I am able to read an mp3 file using mediaplay from the same folder that XML file is saved. Using DocumentBuilderFactory to open XML file.

```
private Document loadSongDictionary() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    String DictionaryFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Documents/SkyePlayerData/Dictionary.xml";
    File inputFile = new File(DictionaryFile);
    Log.i("Main", "File Exists: " + inputFile.exists() + " can read: " + inputFile.canRead()); // I get true for file exists and false for can read.
    if (!getPermissionToReadFile()) return null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    return doc;
}

private boolean getPermissionToReadFile() {

    if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ) {
// I don't get here. I am not asked to grant permission
        requestPermissions( new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },123 );
    }

    return true;
}
```

The logs:

```
I/Main: File Exists: true can read: false
E/PickSong: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/SkyePlayerData/Dictionary.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 introduced a new storage paradigm called scoped storage. You have to update your app according to the guideline to use scoped storage.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

Temporarily you can do the following things:

case 1: If your app targeted below API Level 30 use  'requestLegacyExternalStorage=true' in manifest file

case 2: If your app targeted API Level 30 usepreserveLegacyExternalStorage=true https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#preserveLegacyExternalStorage